# Reading csv file and converting it into numeric

Tags: r

While using R, I read a csv file and used colClasses="character", it convereted all the columns to character but I want the numeric columns(which contain commas) to remain numeric and be stored as they are in the same vector, how do I do that?
I tried out as.numeric(gsub(", ","",stocks$Open)) but the problem with this is that it is not reflected back in the vector permanently.

Comment: please provide reproducible example when you ask something

Comment: See here for help on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Currently your question is a little vague.  Consider posting the first five rows of your data file, the code you are using to read that data and the result that you want.

Comment: ?You may want to specify `as.is=TRUE` rather than `colClasses`.

Answer (score 0):

When passing the argument colClasses, you can specify each column's class separately. For example,

file<-read.csv("filename.csv", colClasses=c("character", "numeric", "numeric"...)

Alternatively, you could convert the columns that you want in numeric form to numeric after reading the file. This can be done using the function as.numeric(). For example,

file[,1]<-as.numeric(file[,1])

Hope it helps!